# How can I see the IDAPython implementation of HexRay's decompiler API?

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

I am trying to use [HexRay's decompiler API](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=107), however having trouble due to its lack of documentation. Is there any means so That I can get to see the Python implementation of decompiler API?

Comment: The actual source files should be contained in your IDA's python distribution (idaapi.py, idc.py, ..).. I fear there is no decent documentation

Comment: Those are stubs generated by SWIG

Comment: yes, but they are still the "Python implementation of decompiler API".

Comment: I guess that the actual logic is wrapped inside corresponding `.so` libraries

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember IDA license allows reverse engineering of IDA itself.
If suggestion that same rule is applicable to the decompiler is correct - the most approachable way to see the implementation is to reverse engineer the plugin - despite the fact that at least part of it should be significantly obfuscated.

There is, however, additional source of the information you can use, the documentation about C++ decompiler SDK is opened and can be found [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk).

It includes the source of hexrays.hpp file ([here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/sdk/hexrays_8hpp_source.shtml)) with decent amount of comments that may be helpful.